Problem faced during running flutter app in vs code using Android emulator
It shows an error
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\SRIKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
Warning: Failed to download package!
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" failed.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\SRIKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@9b08c592" (build-tools;30.0.3) should be installed in
"C:\Users\SRIKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3" but
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\SRIKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3-2" instead.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\SRIKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3-2
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Failed to install the following SDK components:
tools Android SDK Tools
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23m 58s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
I want to clear the above error show by vscode
